# WEKA output extra information

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I wrote a custom classifier for WEKA, and it needs to provide information besides just a predicted class for an instance. Specifically, it is a list describing how great the effect of each of a subset of the training instances was on the predicted class.

The `additionalMeasureProducer` interface will not work, since I need to print a string to the GUI. I would like the user to be able to choose to output this information. I had hoped that the option "Output model" in the "Classifier evaluation options" dialog box would do the trick, but WEKA ends up calling my classifier's `toString()` method before classification has happened. I consider this a bug, since my classifier is in the `weka.classifiers.lazy` package, meaning that it isn't built until the Instance to be classified is given to it.

Does anyone have any idea how to add more GUI output capabilities to a custom WEKA classifier?

Comment: This seems to be quite a specialized Weka question. You might also want to ask it on the Weka mailing list: http://list.scms.waikato.ac.nz/mailman/listinfo/wekalist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the only way I could find to do this properly was to implement a special `weka.classifiers.evaluation.output.prediction.AbstractOutput` which could only be used with my classifier. I specified it with `globalInfo()`, and `getDisplay()`, and my `doPrintClassification` method starts like this:

```
@Override
protected void doPrintClassification(Classifier classifier, Instance inst,
        int index) throws Exception {
    if (!(classifier instanceof MyClassifier))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "This output can only be used with the MyClassifier classifier");

    MyClassifier mc = (MyClassifier) classifier;
```

That way I was able to call the proper methods to get the information for my classifier. Writing it all for CSV, HTML and plaintext was too much, so I just leave it to the user's choice to get special information from my custom output class and get regular information from the other output classes if they desire a specific format.